# Python Pandas can only compare identically-labelled series objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have three data frame. Here's my code and I am getting value error.
`raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")`

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.

Here is my code:

```
df1
df2
df3
for i in df1:                 # for i from df1
     x = df2.loc[df2['col_1'] == i, 'col_2']   #looking for i in col_1 of df2 and getting coresponding value of col_2 as x.
     y = df3.loc[df3['col_1'] == x, 'col_2']   #looking for x in col_1 of df3 and getting coresponding value of col_2 as y
```

The first statement in `for` loop runs correctly but getting value error in second statement.

Comment: when you run `for i in df1` , `i` only takes the column name of `df1`. I don't think that's what you want. are you iterating over rows of `df1`?

Comment: df1 has only one column. it runs fine when i commented the 2nd line of  'for' loop.

Comment: so you might have multiple matches in `x` and `x` is not a single value. You can try this `x = df2.loc[df2['col_1'] == i, 'col_2'].iloc[0]` .

Comment: Have you tried [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53645882/4985099) ?

Comment: no mutiple matches in x... and above also not worked.

Comment: not tried merge yet

Comment: Please provide also subsets of all your DataFrames with which your error occurs.
It is impossible to check how your code works without data is operates on.

Comment: here are subsets of my df's
`#df1`

`500`          
`459 `        
`722`
`273 `

`#df2`
`500          a`
`459         d`
`722          b`
`273           c`

`#df3`
`a        100`
`b        200`
`c       300`
`d      400`

Comment: if m wiritng like `y = df3.loc[df3['col_1'] == 'x', 'col_2']` then the value error is gone. but  still it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your 3 DataFrames have the following content:

```
df1:                df2:              df3:
       Aa    Bb       col_1 col_2       col_1 col_2
0  123.15  12.6     0    Aa    Cc     0    Cc    Gg
1  137.53  28.3     1    Bb    Dd     1    Dd    Hh
                    2    Bb    Ee     2    Ee    Jj
                                      3    Ff    Kk
```

In the first turn of your loop *i* contains the name of the first column
in *df1*, i.e. *'Aa'*.

When you execute `x = df2.loc[df2['col_1'] == i, 'col_2']`, the result is
a *Series*:

```
0    Cc
Name: col_2, dtype: object
```

And now, even if you attempted to execute `df3['col_1'] == x`, your error occurs.

Note that in this case both *df3['col_1']* and *x* are of *Series* type.
In this case:

- the first thing *Pandas* does is to **align** both *Series* (on the index),
- and then it would compare each pair of (aligned) elements.

But in this case:

- *df3['col_1']* contains indices *0* thru *3*,
- the index in *x* contains only **one** position - *0*.

So there is alignment failure, which causes this exception.

To cope with this issue, change the offending line to:

```
y = df3.loc[df3['col_1'].isin(x), 'col_2']
```

Now *Pandas* operates just as you intended:

- iterates over *df3['col_1']*,
- for the current element checks whether its value is among values
  present in *x*,
- if it is, value from *col_2* in the current row is added to
  the result.

To demonstrate how this code works, complete it with some printouts:

```
for i in df1:
    print(f'\ni: {i}')
    x = df2.loc[df2['col_1'] == i, 'col_2']
    print(f'\nx:\n{x}')
    y = df3.loc[df3['col_1'].isin(x), 'col_2']
    print(f'\ny:\n{y}')
```

When you run the above code, on my data, the result is:

```
i: Aa

x:
0    Cc
Name: col_2, dtype: object

y:
0    Gg
Name: col_2, dtype: object

i: Bb

x:
1    Dd
2    Ee
Name: col_2, dtype: object

y:
1    Hh
2    Jj
Name: col_2, dtype: object
```